# SUM of sales from another table in specific date range for each unique user

Tags: sql

need a little help. I have started a select that calculate date ranges in which i want to calculate sales for each agent. Each agent have different date range. But sales are stored in another table.

```
SELECT  [bID]
        ,[pID]
        ,[aID] AS 'AgentID'
        ,[NAME]
        ,[aStart]
        ,'2021-03-01' AS 'Date_from'
        ,case when DATEADD(DAY, 364, aStart) <= '2022-02-28' then DATEADD(DAY, 364, aStart) else '2022-02-28' END) AS 'Date_end'
        ,'' AS 'Sales'
FROM [Agents] as a
WHERE STATUS = 'Active'
AND aStart >= '2020-03-02'
```

Table with sales looks like this:

```
SELECT [aID] AS 'AgentID'
  ,[SalesDate]
  ,[Product]
  ,[Kind]
  ,[SalesSum]
FROM [Sales] as s
```

What i want to do is to calculate **SUM** of all **SalesSum** for each agent, but in specific, calculated date range. In other words i should to add somewhere WHERE clause for s.SalesDate BETWEEN a.Date_from AND a.Date_end. I understand that the answer is somewhere very close, but my brain does not want to focus on it.

Comment: Which dbms you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use join or subquery to do so.

**Using subquery:**

```
ELECT  [bID]
        ,[pID]
        ,[aID] AS 'AgentID'
        ,[NAME]
        ,[aStart]
        ,'2021-03-01' AS 'Date_from'
        ,case when DATEADD(DAY, 364, aStart) <= '2022-02-28' then DATEADD(DAY, 364, aStart) else '2022-02-28' END) AS 'Date_end'
        ,(select sum(salessum) from [Sales]  s where a.aid=s.aid and s.[SalesDate] between '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-15') AS 'Sales'
FROM [Agents] as a
WHERE STATUS = 'Active'
AND aStart >= '2020-03-02'
```

(Please change the date range in subquery as you desire)

Answer (score 1):

you can get the sum for each agent using an outer apply, such as

```
select a.<columns>, s.Tot
from Agents a 
outer apply (
    select Sum(SalesSum) Tot
    from Sales s
    where s.aId=a.aId and s.salesdate between @StartDate and @EndDate
)s
where a.[status]='Active'
and a.aStart>='20200302'
```